# Absolute Imports in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I recently created a ReactJS application, however, I cannot get the babel module resolver to work.
I did not start the project using CRA but npm init.

The error i'm getting is

```html
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@src/components/Component' in '/Users/path/to/app/src'
```

This is my babel.config ts:

```html
module.exports = {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react'],
    plugins: [
        [
            'module-resolver',
            {
                extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
                root: ['.'],
                alias: {
                    '@src': './src',
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
};
```

In my tsconfig.json I also added the following lines:

```html
  "paths": {
    "@src/*": ["./src/*"]
  },
  "include": ["src"]
```

And this is the babel module solver version from my package.json dev dependencies:

```html
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is experiencing similar issues, I managed to make it work by using webpack for absolute imports, and I gave up on babel-module-resolver.

I just added the following in my webpack.config.ts:

```
    resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
            alias: {
                '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
            }
    }
```

And the other part from my tsconfig that I posted above.